# Obtaining the UITableViewHeaderFooterView of a static UITableView

Tags: ios, static, interface-builder, uitableview

I have a Storyboard which contains a `UITableViewController`. The table view is static and contains two sections. The table view was setup entirely in IB (including the header and footer text of the table view sections) - I have not implemented any table view delegate methods in my view controller.

If I attempt to get a reference to the `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` for a given section it always returns nil.

```
UITableViewHeaderFooterView* header =[self.tableView headerViewForSection:0];
```

When I run the app I can see the header and footer text that I set in IB so I know those views are there. I just can't figure out how to access them programmatically.

Any help would be much appreciated,
CS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you'll need to specify the table footer view, and pass it to the table view using its delegate.

For example, suppose you have defined a IBOutlet UIView named tableFooterView.
Then in the following delegate method, you can pass your tableFooterView to your table view:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section;   // custom view for footer. will be adjusted to default or specified footer height
{
    return self.tableFooterView;
}
```

Also you'll need to implement the following method to set the height of the table footer view:

```
 -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
    return self.tableFooterView.frame.size.height;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you Shadowfiend. For some reason I thought that there would be an existing header/footer view since I was able to customize them in IB.

Comment: Actually, there is one, but Apple does not let you access it. They are ruining a lot of nice properties of Cocoa these days.