# FooterView for Static Tableview Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, footer

I have tried just about everything on the internet and I cannot find anything that works.

I have a TableViewController that uses static cells. All I want to do is implement a custom view from a xib as the footer. I have no idea how to load the xib and have it pop up as the footer. Everything I have done hasn't worked and just yields white space.

Sorry for the lack of information.

Thanks!

[Update]

This is a view that I have written:

```
class settingsFoot: UIView {
static let sharedFoot = settingsFoot()

var footview: UIView = UIView()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.addView()
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func addView(){
    footview.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 10, width: 200, height: 100)
    footview.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightText
    self.addSubview(footview)
}
}
```

So, how can I take this view and make it the footer? I forgot to mention in the original post that I only have one section and the footer will simply cover the space below the static cells.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    SettingsTable.tableFooterView = settingsFoot.sharedFoot
    }
```

This is what I tried, but I still have a white background when I run.

Thanks! #2

Comment: Check this, its should work [link here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556086/obtaining-the-uitableviewheaderfooterview-of-a-static-uitableview)

Comment: How can I do this in Swift 3.0

Comment: try this method to return your view and height for them http://stackoverflow.com/a/40554164/1142743 .

Comment: So, I would implement these two methods and then load the custom view in the viewForFooter function?